# Does icloud storage get freed up automatically after 30 days?

Tags: icloud

I just bought an iphone a day before and started turned on icloud.
Although I am using a mac since 4 years but never considered using icloud.

I wanted to know if icloud storage gets cleared up on its own after 30 days?
In any case I would want to do it if possible.

I did search settings in my phone and it has some options like `download originals`. I am unsure about these.

What I want is that the photos I click in get automatically saved to my mac aswell. I just want to use icloud for a 30 day backup.

Comment: I think you might need to read https://support.apple.com/en-us/HT204264 .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome to Ask Different.

iCloud doesn't get cleared after 30 days, or ever (unless done manually). As for saving photos to your mac, that can be done manually from [icloud.com](https://www.icloud.com). You can also access them from the Photos app on your mac by enabling iCloud Photos Library from System Preferences.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Although I would want to automate this process somehow with scripts. Till what I read, if I delete photos from any of the devices, it gets deleted from all unless i download originals. So when they r on my mac, i could make a script to copy them to other directory and remove from icloud directory.

Comment: I'm not sure that can be done unless jailbroken, because you regularly can't access the iCloud (except with Photos) or iOS directories where the photos are stored. The only possible way that I can think of doing this (without being jailbroken) is by automatically backing up and extracting photos using iMazing, though that wouldn't be a script. If jailbroken, you can create a script that uses scp to access and copy over all photos.